# Is there an Android developer API for app review and launch?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, android-developer-api

I'm trying to fully automate the entire process of app publishing/updating to the play store by using google's API's.

So far I have found Fastlane tool which allows me to upload apk's files to any line (alpha, beta, production, etc.) but only upload them. There i don't have any other option than accessing the Google play console by web browser and review and publish them manually.

I have also looked at the google play developer API documentation and i haven't found any API related specifically to review and publish of the apps, all i have found are the API's for apk's uploads (via edits).

So my question is: is there any way to automate the process of review and launch of the app through API's?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Google Developer API Edits:commit to make your changes live. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/commit

Comment: As far as i saw there is no way with the edits set of apis to execute the action of review and launch. You can upload apks, create new versions or promote a beta version to a production version, but i haven't found a way to actually review and launch the version to the store. The only way i found to execute these two tasks are through the play store console